# What dependencies does gmp's libgmp.so have? I keep getting undefined references

Tags: c++, linker, dependencies, g++, gmp

I am trying to get gmp working so I can use large integers. I've compiled it ok but when I try to compile my code with it I keep getting errors such as:

```
.../libgmp.so: undefined reference to `__gmpn_sublsh2_n'
```

My compile line is,

```
g++ -g -std=c++11 -I ../gmp-6.1.2 test.cpp -L../gmp-6.1.2/.libs -lgmp -lgmpxx
```

`libgmpxx.so` is definitely in the specified lib directory.

I can't find any references to similar problems or any reference in the docs to dependencies for libgmp.so (shouldn't it be linking with libgmpxx.so?).

I'm sure I've missed something obvious and will feel the fool when someone points it out, but at the moment I'm losing it.

Comment: It's not simply a question of not finding the library; the message would be completely different if that were the problem.  It's a question of not finding certain C symbols that should be defined in the library (or one of the libraries).  Should you be using `libtool` or perhaps `pkg-conf` to sort out flags?  The use of the `.libs` subdirectory suggests that — normally, shared objects are in a `lib` subdirectory, not a `.libs` subdirectory.

Comment: Are you sure your actual error message references libgmp.so and not libgmpxx.so? If the former, your libgmp build could be broken. If the latter, try switching places of -lgmp and -lgmpxx.

Comment: the .libs directory was created by gmp, not me. I am happy to move it somewhere more 'usual', but I doubt that will affect anything.

Comment: Also, it definitely mentions libgmp.so, not libgmpxx.so. I thought that was unusual too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you guys, I seem to have found the problem. You got me thinking about the location of libgmpxx.so. I copied it into /usr/local where I found libgmp.so and adjusted my library paths (-L) and hey presto! Clearly the undefined references are defined in libgmp.so upon which libgmpxx.so depends and could not find in the directory where it lived (.libs) or in the search path.

Thanks again.